# dart path dependencies not working (across multiple projects)

Tags: file, dependencies, dart

I was attempting to make a "library" type of project in dart and then "depend" on that library from another project (all using the path dependency functionality of the yaml file).  I understand that I might be able to get the dependency stuff to work if I hosted my library or if I used GIT, but I don't want to do either, because I feel that pure filesystem based dependencies should be a "no brainer".

So, without further adieu, here is my situation.  I have a very simple dart library/project based on web_ui that contains two files:

```
esrvdartui.dart
---------------
library esrvdartui;

import 'dart:html';
import 'package:web_ui/web_ui.dart';

part 'esrvradiobutton.dart';



esrvradiobutton.dart
--------------------
part of esrvdartui;

class ESrvRadioButton extends RadioButtonInputElement
{
  ESrvRadioButton ()
  {
  }
}
```

I then created another very small/simple web_ui based project called "ExampleForm" that wants to use my esrvdartui project above.  Both of these projects exist in the same directory structure.  My ExampleForm project contains the following yaml file:

```
pubspec.yaml
------------
name: ExampleForm
description: A sample WebUI application
dependencies:
  js: any
  browser: any
  web_ui: any
  esrvdartui:
    path: ../esrvdartui
```

No matter what I set my path to in the above yaml file, I never see my web\packages directory underneath of my ExampleForm project get updated with my files from the esrvdartui project and as such, I cannot use the files in my library using the file based dependency method, because the build fails for my ExampleForm project.

"Pub install" does not complain with the above path and it doesn't complain when I use an absolute path, so I know that "Pub install" see my dependent project.  It just doesn't copy the darned files for me.

Any thoughts?

My pubspec.lock file for ExampleForm is:

# Generated by pub
 # See http://pub.dartlang.org/doc/glossary.html#lockfile
 {"packages":{"logging":{"version":"0.5.0+1","source":"hosted","description":"logging"},"source_maps":{"version":"0.5.0+1","source":"hosted","description":"source_maps"},"unittest":{"version":"0.5.0+1","source":"hosted","description":"unittest"},"pathos":{"version":"0.5.0+1","source":"hosted","description":"pathos"},"analyzer_experimental":{"version":"0.4.7+1","source":"hosted","description":"analyzer_experimental"},"web_ui":{"version":"0.4.6+1","source":"hosted","description":"web_ui"},"js":{"version":"0.0.21","source":"hosted","description":"js"},"csslib":{"version":"0.4.3","source":"hosted","description":"csslib"},"esrvdartui":{"version":"0.0.0","source":"path","description":{"relative":false,"path":"C:/Users/Jason/dart/esrvdartui"}},"html5lib":{"version":"0.4.3","source":"hosted","description":"html5lib"},"args":{"version":"0.5.0+1","source":"hosted","description":"args"},"browser":{"version":"0.5.0+1","source":"hosted","description":"browser"},"meta":{"version":"0.5.0+1","source":"hosted","description":"meta"}}}

My pubspec.lock file for esrvdartui is:

## Generated by pub

## See http://pub.dartlang.org/doc/glossary.html#lockfile

{"packages":{"meta":"version":"0.5.0+1","source":"hosted","description":"meta"},"browser":{"version":"0.5.0+1","source":"hosted","description":"browser"},"args":{"version":"0.5.0+1","source":"hosted","description":"args"},"html5lib":{"version":"0.4.3","source":"hosted","description":"html5lib"},"analyzer_experimental":{"version":"0.5.0+1","source":"hosted","description":"analyzer_experimental"},"csslib":{"version":"0.4.3","source":"hosted","description":"csslib"},"web_ui":{"version":"0.4.6+1","source":"hosted","description":"web_ui"},"pathos":{"version":"0.5.0+1","source":"hosted","description":"pathos"},"js":{"version":"0.0.22","source":"hosted","description":"js"},"source_maps":{"version":"0.5.0+1","source":"hosted","description":"source_maps"},"unittest":{"version":"0.5.0+1","source":"hosted","description":"unittest"},"logging":{"version":"0.5.0+1","source":"hosted","description":"logging"}}}

Comment: Can you add your pubspec.lock as an edit to your question?

Comment: My guess would be that your dart files are in `web` instead of `lib`? Using pub with local paths creates a hardlink to "[your_folder]\lib".

Comment: I have the same problem, would be really interested in a solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally got this to work, but for the life of me, I couldn't find this documented anywhere.  All you have to do is create a project in the Dart IDE.  Then, create a top level folder in that project called "lib" (blow all other directories away other than the top level "packages" folder).  Now, create your main library's .dart file.  Let's call it "mylibrary.dart".  This contents of this file will look something like this:

**mylibrary.dart**

```
 library mylibrary;

 import 'dart:json';

 part 'src/libraryfile1.dart';
```

Now, create a sub-directory underneath of "lib" to place your library's source files into.  This can really be named anything, but I choose to name it "src".  Place your libraryfile1.dart file  there and it should look something like this:

**src/libraryfile1.dart**

```
 part of hix_lib;
 .
 .
 .
```

All import statements should always be placed in your top-level main library file:  mylibrary.dart.

Now, in the project that you wish to use this file-based library in, you must add your "mylibrary" to your project's pubspec.yaml file and choose: "Source: path".  On my machine, because all projects are in the same directory, my path simply points to:  ../mylibrary

And that's all there is to do!!!!!